# 'NSString' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<NSObject, AnyObject>'

Tags: swift

I try to rewrite some objective c code into swift. Now I get a very strange error. I tried the code in a playgroud, absolutely untouched from other code.

Here is the part, I want to translate:

```
NSDictionary *info = [self infoForBinding:@"theBinding"];
[[info objectForKey:NSObservedObjectKey] 
        setValue:MyValue 
        forKeyPath:[info objectForKey:NSObservedKeyPathKey]];
```

This is the code, I tried:

```
class x: NSButtonCell {

    func a() {
        var info = infoForBinding("theBinding")
        info[NSObservedObjectKey]?.setValue(nil, forKeyPath: info[NSObservedKeyPathKey])
    }

}
```

Now I get the error `'NSString' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex<NSObject, AnyObject>'`. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

This is working... I don't know why.

```
info[NSObservedObjectKey]?.setValue(MyValue forKeyPath: (info[NSObservedKeyPathKey] as NSString))
```

Comment: Have you tried casting `info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]` as a `String` before passing it to `setValue`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. I updated my question. Casting as NSString works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that

```
info[NSObservedObjectKey]?.setValue(MyValue forKeyPath: (info[NSObservedKeyPathKey] as NSString))
```

works is that as of beta 3, the `NSDictionary#getValue` method returns a DictionaryIndex object instead of casting it to an NSObject/AnyObject.  By explicitly casting it (which is something to get into a good practice of, as the Swift designers seem to be opposed to too much implict casting), you can safely pass it into `setValue` without any ruckus.